# How to ignore whitespace in xml comparison in MUnit

Tags: unit-testing, mule, munit

When doing an MUnit test to check a dataweave output I am comparing the payload to a file which has been read using the getResource() method.

```
<munit:assert-on-equals expectedValue="#[getResource('examplexml.xml').asString()]" actualValue="#[payload]" doc:name="Assert Equals"/>
```

The error seen says that what is expected is not what is seen despite the fact they look identical. This must be due to the way Object-To-String works in Mule. Is there a way to compare the values as opposed to the whitespace?

Comment: Please check this link https://forums.mulesoft.com/questions/70057/issues-asserting-an-applicationjson-payload-that-i.html

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

1. The simplest but least flexible way is to make your examplexml.xml file match up exactly, including the whitespaces to your actual payload.
2. A less brittle way but more coding is to convert both your xml payloads into a common object and assert against each individual attribute.
3. More functionality than you need but a clean solution is to use the community created Assert Object connector, https://github.com/rbutenuth/assert-object-equals-connector. Check out this [blog](https://blogs.mulesoft.com/dev/anypoint-platform-dev/easier-assertions-xml-json-in-munit/) for implementation details.